# Use of 'breakdown'

Tags: meaning-in-context

What would be the meaning of this:"In this guide we hope to **breakdown the skills** needed to answer the questions." How does this '**breakdown the skills**' sound? Is there a better way to say this?

Comment: "breakdown" should be two words.

Comment: This could drift into 're-writing'. Are you going to take the individual skills and break them down into smaller skills?(sentence is correct then) If you mean "break down the questions to highlight specific skills required to answer them" , your grammar doesn't fit my rewording.

Answer (score 1):

It should be "break down the skills", because a "breakdown" refers to the *result* of breaking something down, such as "a breakdown of the skills needed to answer the questions" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/breakdown

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the spelling mistake is corrected.

> "In this guide we hope to break down the skills needed to answer the questions."

("Breakdown" is a noun and "break down" is a verb.)

This means

> In this guide we hope to list and explain, one by one, each of the skills needed.

***[break down](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/break+down)***

> 6. To divide into or consider in parts; analyze. To be divisible; admit of analysis: The population breaks down into three main groups.

*(American Heritage)*

The sentence as you included it will be fine once the space is inserted between *break* and *down*.